# Github page links behave differently offline and online

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a small [github pages site](http://simonh1000.github.io/). Offline - using Jekyll - I need to set up links to e.g. `/blog.html` but these do not work online, where I seem to need `/blog`. But the latter does not work offline. How can I get the same behaviour offline and online?

```
/ index.html
- blog.html
- decoder.md
-   / _includes
    - navbar.html
```

And this in navbar.html

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="topbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li> -->
            <li><a href="/decoder">Elm Json tester</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: very hard to say without any example code or directory layout. do you have any examples?

Comment: @NilsWerner That's a reasonable request - have added :-)

Comment: Are you serving your local page using jekyll, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github pages is now running Jekyll 3.x.

Locally, you can do a `bundle update`. Be sure to check everything is ok before pushing to github, they are some breaking changes.

You can read the [2 > 3 migration's documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/).